# Bouncing ball resets to desired position but does not move

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a squash game and thought setting up the ball movement would be a good place to start. I have managed to get the ball bouncing the way I want it, it drops from 50px from the top left corner, bounces twice and then resets back to where it started. Instead of continuously moving after resetting, the ball just stays at 50px from top corner. 
Why is the ball not moving after resetting? How do I get the ball to move from resetting? 
From here I want to set an event listener to restart the ball dropping to "serve" the ball again after. Any advice on where to place this would be awesome. This is my first attempt at coding my own game so bear in mind I am a complete noob.

Here is my canvas code.

```
<html>
<title>Squash Game V1</title>

<h1>Squash</h1>

 <canvas id="gameCanvas" width=800 height=600></canvas>

 <script>

 var canvas;
 var canvasContext;
 var ballX = 50;
 var ballY = 50;
 var gravity = 0.2;
 var bounceFactor = 0.6;
 var ballSpeedX = 3;
 var ballSpeedY = 10;
 var ballSpeedY2 = 5;
 var ballBounce = 0
 var ballStartPos = 50
 const resistence = 0.998
 const ballWidth = 15;


 window.onload = function() {

 canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
 canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

 var framesPerSecond = 60;
 setInterval(function() {
 moveEverything();
 drawEverything();


 }, 1000/framesPerSecond);
 }



 function ballReset() { 
 ballX = ballStartPos;
 ballY = ballStartPos;
             }



 function moveEverything() {



 // this moves ball down
 ballY += ballSpeedY;

 // this moves the ball across 
 ballX += ballSpeedX;

 // this speeds ball up as it's falling plus slows down making it fall  

 ballSpeedY += gravity;
 ballSpeedX = ballSpeedX*resistence;


 //this bounes the ball
 if (ballY > canvas.height - ballWidth) {
 ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY
 //this reduces height of the bounce
 ballSpeedY *= bounceFactor;}

 //this should count bounces
 if (ballY > canvas.height - ballWidth){
 ballBounce = ballBounce + 1;
 }



 //ball will bounce of right wall 
 if (ballX > canvas.width - ballWidth) {
 ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX}

 //ball will bounce off left wall 
 if (ballX < 0 + ballWidth) {
 ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX}

 if (ballBounce >= 2) {
 ballReset()}


 }


 function drawEverything() {
 //this draws the pong court
 colourRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height, 'black');

 //this draws the ball
 colourCircle(ballX, ballY, 10, "white")



 function colourCircle(centreX, centreY, radius, drawColour) {
 canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColour;
 canvasContext.beginPath();
 canvasContext.arc(centreX, centreY, radius, 0,Math.PI*2, true)
 canvasContext.fill();
 }

        //this function draws a rectangle
        function colourRect(leftX, topY, width, height, drawColour) {
            canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColour;
        canvasContext.fillRect(leftX, topY, width, height);

        } }

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ball stops bouncing because your current code continuously calls ballReset() after the second bounce. You should reset the `ballBounce` counter in the reset method to keep it bouncing. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1hgcx2p/5/)

```
function ballReset() {
     ballX = ballStartPos;
     ballY = ballStartPos;
     ballBounce = 0; // Added code
 }
```

Comment: probably want the speeds reset too